# Debugging phantom zsh process

Tags: mojave, bash, launchd, iterm, zsh

Every once in a while (once a week?) I noticed that my mac's fans are spinning full speed. When I investigate my processes on activity monitor I notice a zsh process consuming near 100% on the cpu. Shutting down this process fixes the issue, as it doesn't go away on it own. The fans also continue to spin full power when close the lid.

I'm trying to track the source of this process and hopefully fix the issue. The zsh process's parent is launchd (PID 1). I've tried to find a matching daemons and agents file but nothing jumps out at me. Similarly I tired looking at the open file and ports to get an idea of what the process is doing but didn't lead to any insights.

I'm running macOS 10.14.6 on a 2015 Macbook Pro. My default shell is zsh despite the default being bash in Mojave. I suspect the issue is that something that is supposed to launch using bash launches with zsh and gets confused, but that's just a hunch.

I know this isn't a lot to go on hence this question has two possible goals:

- figure out the cause/fix of this specific runaway process
- recommend general tools for tracking and debugging such processes (so that I can figure it out/post more information here)

Comment: Remove your custom ZSH configuration.  Does the orphaned process now not occur?

Comment: I'll disable it and report back (although its hard to know with stuff that crops up non-deterministicly)

Comment: I think the point is that it most likely won't.  Next time it happens, look at the process tree and see what this shell process is actually doing.

Comment: By process tree you mean ‘pstree’. I’ve already done that and it only launches another zsh process and nothing else. (No grandchild processes either)

Comment: Presumably shell script being run should be noted somewhere - I’ll defiantly double check opened files and such